# Using LIMIT function is subquery

Tags: sql, oracle, limit

I am using this query:

```
select city, length(city) 
from station 
where length(city) = (select max(length(city)) from station ) 
   OR length(city) = (select min(length(city)) from station) 
order by city asc;
```

and when I add LIMIT function to my subqueries, because I need exactly one result from that select:

```
select city, length(city) 
from station 
where length(city) = (select max(length(city)) from station limit 1) 
   OR length(city) = (select min(length(city)) from station limit 1) 
order by city asc;
```

then I got error -

```
ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
```

Anybody who has idea where I make mistake with that function. I use Oracle, I tried to use rownum but it didn't help.

Comment: Oracle doesn't support `limit`.  It is not needed anyway, so just remove it.

Comment: @GordonLinoff is right, no need the limit, the `MAX` and `MIN` will you give just 1 row

Comment: well for my first select I got: 
 `   Marine On Saint Croix 21 

    Roy 3 

    Lee 3 

    Amo 3 `

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use `max()` then `limit` is not required :

```
select city, length(city) 
from station 
where length(city) = (select max(length(city)) 
                      from station
                     ) OR 
      length(city) = (select min(length(city)) 
                      from station 
                     ) 
order by city asc;
```

However, `limit` will not support in `Oracle`.

Comment: The reason why I wanted to use limit is that - that I had at least 3 cities in my table which have same length. Therefore it works for MAX but not for MIN subquery. So, should I use ROWNUM ?

Answer (score 0):

Oracle does not support the `limi [n]t` syntax. The equivalent is the `fetch first [n] rows only` (available starting Oracle 12c).

But bottom line: each of the subqueries is guaranteed to return only one record, so there is just no need for `limit`.

I would furthermore suggest to rewrite the queries to use `rank()`, which avoids the need for multiple subqueries, and, in my opinion, makes the logic clearer:

```
select city, length_city
from (
    select 
        city, 
        lenght(city) length_city,
        rank() over(order by length(city)) rn_asc,
        rank() over(order by length(city) desc) rn_desc
    from station
) t
where rn_asc = 1 or rn_desc = 1
```

If you want have top/bottom ties and you just want one of them, then you can add an additional ordering criteria to the ranking function: for example, `order by length(city), city` gives you the first city, alphabetically-wise, in case of duplicates.

Comment: That is interesting. I have 3 cities with length 3. So I got 3 results.

Comment: @PavelPetr:I updated my answer with more details on how to break the ties.